# TypeDoc fails with static block

Tags: typedoc

TypeDoc does not understand TypeScript static blocks.  Static blocks were added to TypeScript 4.4.   I am using TypeDoc 0.22.17 which claims to support TypeScript versions 4.0 through 4.7
https://typedoc.org/guides/installation/

Is there something else I need to do to make TypeDoc understand static blocks in TypeScript?

---

For example of problem, here is file "src/hello.js":

```
/**
 * My class
 */
export class HelloWorld {
    constructor() {
        console.log("Hello World");
    }

    static {
        new HelloWorld();
    }
}
```

... and "tsconfig.json":

```
      {
        "compilerOptions": {
          "module": "ES2020",
          "target": "ES6",
          "sourceMap": true,
          "outDir": "build",
        },
        "include": [
          "src/**/*"
        ],
      }
```

When I run "npx typedoc -out html src/hello.ts"  I get the following error messages:

```
Error: src/hello.ts:9:11 - error TS1146: Declaration expected.

9     static {
            

Error: src/hello.ts:9:12 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

9     static {
             ~

Error: src/hello.ts:12:1 - error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

12 }
```

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce this, but it looks to me like TypeDoc is using a different version of TypeScript than you think it is. I'd recommend trying `npx typedoc --version`, which will print out the TypeScript version and where it is located.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Gerrit0 wrote, you need to check the version of TypeDoc is as expected *and* TypeDoc's version of TypeScript is as expected too. The command "npx typedoc --version" prints both versions.